# WebView choosing file and Activity recreation

Tags: android, webview, filechooser

There is an app where the Users Onboarding Flow is implemented as a Web page and it is being shown in the embedded WebView. One of that flow steps is a file uploading.

It is implemented by using `<input/>` tag on the web page and further handling it by an overridden `WebChromeClient.onShowFileChooser(..., filePathCallback: ValueCallback<Array<Uri>>?, ...)` which eventually triggers `startActivityForResult(...)` which is supposed to start provided by the platform File-Chooser-Activity (can be different for different vendors/version).

And as usual, everything works fine until the activity is being destroyed :)

The problem is when the File-Chooser-Activity is started on top of the app's activity the last one can be destroyed (by the system due the lack of resources, rotation, ... ). Then the WebView whose `filePathCallback` we have will be destroyed too. This means the app does not have at this point the valid `filePathCallback` when it gets URI for the chosen file (upon `onActivityResult`).

How do you people solve this problem?

I have created a simple project which represents the issue in isolation, feel free to check it out:
https://github.com/allco/WebViewFileChooseIssue

Here is some video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9mnd0lT9lZI

Case #2 demonstrates the problem, the app still shows "No file chosen" even when the choice is done.

Here is the clipped snippet with a key file from the project:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    companion object {
        const val REQ_CODE_CHOOSER = 1
    }

    val unencodedHtml = "<input type=file>"
    var webViewFileChooseCallback: ValueCallback<Array<Uri>>? = null

    private val webClient = object : WebViewClient() {
        ...
    }



    private val chromeClient = object : WebChromeClient() {
        ...
        override fun onShowFileChooser(
            webView: WebView,
            filePathCallback: ValueCallback<Array<Uri>>?,
            fileChooserParams: FileChooserParams?
        ): Boolean {
            if (filePathCallback == null) return false
            webViewFileChooseCallback = filePathCallback
            startFileChooserActivity("*/*")
            return true
        }
    }

    fun startFileChooserActivity(mimeType: String) {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
        intent.type = mimeType
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)

        // special intent for Samsung file manager
        val sIntent = Intent("com.sec.android.app.myfiles.PICK_DATA")
        // if you want any file type, you can skip next line
        sIntent.putExtra("CONTENT_TYPE", mimeType)
        sIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT)

        val chooserIntent: Intent
        if (packageManager.resolveActivity(sIntent, 0) != null) {
            // it is device with Samsung file manager
            chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(sIntent, "Open file")
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, arrayOf(intent))
        } else {
            chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open file")
        }

        try {
            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, REQ_CODE_CHOOSER)
        } catch (ex: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException) {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "No suitable File Manager was found.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val webView = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webView)
        webView.webChromeClient = chromeClient
        webView.webViewClient = webClient

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            val encodedHtml = Base64.encodeToString(unencodedHtml.toByteArray(), Base64.NO_PADDING)
            webView.loadData(encodedHtml, "text/html", "base64")
        } else {
            webView.restoreState(savedInstanceState)
        }
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webView).saveState(outState)
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        when {
            requestCode == REQ_CODE_CHOOSER && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null -> {
                val uri = when {
                    data.dataString != null -> arrayOf(Uri.parse(data.dataString))
                    data.clipData != null -> (0 until data.clipData!!.itemCount)
                        .mapNotNull { data.clipData?.getItemAt(it)?.uri }
                        .toTypedArray()
                    else -> null
                }
                webViewFileChooseCallback?.onReceiveValue(uri)
            }
            else -> super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        }
    }
}
```